# NextJS: Push new query string value to an existing asPath or update the existing query string

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am kinda lost on how the NextJS router system works:

I have articles by categories that can be:

```
Medical
Charity
Wedding
Funeral
```

I am having a navbar where the user can display articles by category, and can also search by a keyword. The category feature is working perfectly.

This is how my navbar looks like:
[image]

That means if the user clicks on `All`, we are displaying all articles:

Here is the scenario:

- When we click for example on `Medical`, the URL looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/articles?category=medical`
- When we click in `all`, the URL looks like `http://localhost:3000/articles`
- When we click in `all` and search the keyword `COVID`, the URL looks like this: `http://localhost:3000/articles?search=covid`

### PROBLEM

*I now want to combine categories and search*:
If the user clicks in `medical` and searches for the keyword `COVID`, the URL must look like this: `http://localhost:3000/articles?category=medical&search=covid`.

After getting the search result, when the user changes the keyword, I want to replace the `search` query string with the new value.

### HOW I TRIED TO DO?

I know NextJS router [object](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) has:

- `pathname`: Current route. That is the path of the page in /pages
- and `asPath`: Actual path (including the query) shown in the browser

```
const { push, asPath } = useRouter();

const onSearchKeyPress = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const keyword = e.currentTarget.value;
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      url = !isEmpty(keyword.trim())
        ? {
          pathname: asPath,
          query: { search: keyword },
        }
        : {
          pathname,
        };
      push(url);
    }
  };
```

But doing so is encoding the `asPath` and resulting in this URL: `http://localhost:3000/article%3Fcategory=covid&search=covid` which is displaying the `404` page not found.

So, I don't even know if I can replace the `search` with a new value as the user wants to perform a new search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by not using the `asPath`: I instead used the `pathname` alongside the spread operator as follow:

```
url = !isEmpty(keyword.trim())
     ? {
        pathname,
        query: { ...query, search: keyword },
     }: {
        pathname: page,
     };
```